# Send Money to Paypal Account ASP.Net Server Side Code

Tags: paypal, asp.net-core-mvc, paypal-sandbox

I am having a difficult time finding halfway descent documentation or examples on how to send money to another Paypal account.

I have installed the Nuget package PaypalSDK version 1.0.4. I have read the documentation at https://developer.paypal.com/home. I have browsed and tried to implement the sample code at https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NET-SDK.

The problem I am having is that I am having is that I am not seeing notifications of payments sent or received in my sandbox account. I can successfully execute a checkout with the Javascript button in my shopping cart view. But eventually I want to add the capability to send money from my Paypal business account to another Paypal business account, without the other Paypal Business Account owner having to be logged in to my website.

Does the money recipient have to authorize the money I send, or should it just get deposited into their account once I send it?

Here is my code:

```
namespace MyShoppingCart.Helpers.Paypal
{
    public class CaptureOrderSample
    {
        static string PayPalClientID = Startup.StaticConfig.GetValue<string>("Paypal:ClientID");
        static string PayPalClientSecret = Startup.StaticConfig.GetValue<string>("Paypal:ClientSecret");

        public static HttpClient client()
        {
            // Creating a sandbox environment
            PayPalEnvironment environment = new SandboxEnvironment(PayPalClientID, PayPalClientSecret);

            // Creating a client for the environment
            PayPalHttpClient client = new PayPalHttpClient(environment);
            return client;
        }

        public async static Task<HttpResponse> createOrder(string Email)
        {
            HttpResponse response;
            // Construct a request object and set desired parameters
            // Here, OrdersCreateRequest() creates a POST request to /v2/checkout/orders
            var order = new OrderRequest()
            {
                CheckoutPaymentIntent = "CAPTURE",
                PurchaseUnits = new List<PurchaseUnitRequest>()
                {
                    new PurchaseUnitRequest()
                    {
                        AmountWithBreakdown = new AmountWithBreakdown()
                        {
                            CurrencyCode = "USD",
                            Value = "100.00"
                        },
                            Payee = new Payee
                            {
                              Email = Email // "payee@email.com"
                            }
                    }
                }
                
                //,
                //ApplicationContext = new ApplicationContext()
                //{
                //    ReturnUrl = "https://www.example.com",
                //    CancelUrl = "https://www.example.com"
                //}
            };


            // Call API with your client and get a response for your call
            var request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
            request.Prefer("return=representation");
            request.RequestBody(order);
            response = await client().Execute(request);
            var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
            Order result = response.Result<Order>();
            Debug.WriteLine($"Status: {result.Status}");
            Debug.WriteLine($"Order Id: {result.Id}");
            Debug.WriteLine($"Intent: {result.CheckoutPaymentIntent}");
            Debug.WriteLine("Links:");
            foreach (LinkDescription link in result.Links)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"\t{link.Rel}: {link.Href}\tCall Type: { link.Method}");
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is currently called from my Orders controller when an order is completed. This is just for testing purposes.

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> CompleteOrder()
{
    var items = _shoppingCart.GetShoppingCartItems();


    Models.Order order = await _ordersService.StoreOrderAsync(items);

    PrepareSellerEmail(items, order, "You Have a New Order!");
    PrepareBuyerEmail(items, order, "Thank You for Your Order!");
    await _shoppingCart.ClearShoppingCartAsync(_serviceProvider);
    DeleteCartIDCookie();

    //OrderRequest request = Helpers.CreateOrderSample.BuildRequestBody("USD", "100.00", "sb-r43z1e9186231@business.example.com");
    //var client =  Helpers.Paypal.CaptureOrderSample.client();

    var result = Helpers.Paypal.CaptureOrderSample.createOrder("sb-r43z1e9186231@business.example.com");

    //var response = await PayPalClient.client().execute.(request);

    return View("OrderCompleted");
}
```

The output of the result is:

```
Status: CREATED
Order Id: 51577255GE4475222
Intent: CAPTURE
Links:
    self: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/51577255GE4475222   Call Type: GET
    approve: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=51577255GE4475222 Call Type: GET
    update: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/51577255GE4475222 Call Type: PATCH
    capture: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/51577255GE4475222/capture    Call Type: POST
```

This is a screen capture from my sandbox account:
[image]

Am I supposed to do something else to actually execute the transfer?

Edit: I figured out how to use the Paypal Payouts API.

First I installed the Nuget Package. It's simply called `PayoutsSdk`. I'm using version 1.1.1.

For the payout to execute, you need the `client()` method that is listed above in this post, and this `CreatePayout()` method listed below.

```
public async static Task<HttpResponse> CreatePayout()
{
    var body = new CreatePayoutRequest()
    {
        SenderBatchHeader = new SenderBatchHeader()
        {
            EmailMessage = "Congrats on recieving 1$",
            EmailSubject = "You recieved a payout!!"
        },
        Items = new List<PayoutItem>()  
        {
            new PayoutItem()
            {
                RecipientType="EMAIL",
                Amount=new Currency()
                {
                    CurrencyCode="USD",
                    Value="1",
                },
                Receiver="sb-r43z1e9186231@business.example.com",
            }
        }
    };
    PayoutsPostRequest request = new PayoutsPostRequest();
    request.RequestBody(body);
    var response = await client().Execute(request);
    var result = response.Result<CreatePayoutResponse>();
    Debug.WriteLine($"Status: {result.BatchHeader.BatchStatus}");
    Debug.WriteLine($"Batch Id: {result.BatchHeader.PayoutBatchId}");
    Debug.WriteLine("Links:");
    foreach (PayoutsSdk.Payouts.LinkDescription link in result.Links)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"\t{link.Rel}: {link.Href}\tCall Type: {link.Method}");
    }

    return response;
}
```

Of course I'll add parameters to the method for email, amount, currency code, email message, and subject.

Right now, I am calling this method from the controller method like this: `var result = Helpers.Paypal.CaptureOrderSample.CreatePayout();` where `Helpers.Paypal` are folders that contain a class called `CaptureOrderSample`, which I will probably rename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send money from your account to another account, there are several different options:

- Automate the sending with the Payouts API or Payouts Web (spreadsheet upload). For live, payouts can only be used if the live account sending the payment is [approved for payouts.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/)
- Log into the account that is going to send the money in https://www.paypal.com or https://www.sandbox.paypal.com and click on the menu for Pay & Get Paid -> Send Money .
- Use a PayPal Checkout integration, with or without the Orders API, and [specify a `payee` that is to receive the money](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/). You must log in with the paying (sending) account to approve the sending, and finally **the order must be captured** (via API or client side `actions.order.capture()`) which is what results in a PayPal transaction. If the final capture step is not performed, no money will be sent and the order will merely remain created or approved and eventually expire (72 hours after creation or 3 hours after approval)

In the sandbox, no actual emails are sent with notifications. Instead, the developer.paypal.com dashboard has a "Notifications" tab on the left, and of course activity will also be visible in each sandbox account by logging into the account. Only captured activity is likely to be visible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So in my case, I am missing the ```actions.order.capture()``` part of the workflow. Would you mind demonstrating that with the Paypal SDK using ASP.Net? The paypal documentation seems to be throwing 404 errors today.

Comment: That function call is only for a pure client-side integration. If you are using ASP.Net for API calls then this is the pattern you need: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , and use the Checkout-Net-SDK or direct HTTPS API calls for the creation and capture from your server.

Comment: I am now getting, "Payer has not yet approved the Order for payment. Please redirect the payer to the 'rel':'approve' url returned as part of the HATEOAS links within the Create Order call or provide a valid payment_source in the request.". I don't want to have to go approve each order, so what I would like to do is provide a valid payment source in the request. How do I do that? I cannot find any documentation on how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Orders must be approved. If you don't want to approve them, don't use orders. Payouts were discussed first in my answer.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you for your patience. I will look into payouts.

Comment: I got the Payouts API to work. I'll update my question to show how to implement a Payout. Thank you!

Comment: Please note that it's subject to business use case approval in the live environment

Comment: Yes, I saw that it's subject to approval. Hopefully they approve me. If they don't, then I guess I'll go looking for another payments processor. Not sure why they would deny me. They get a fee for every payout I process. I updated my original question to show my final implementation.